# How to deal with cold hands at home

Tags: winter

I work on my computer at home as a freelancer and my hands are often so cold I have to put them under me thighs 50 times a day to warm them up.

Are some kind of winter indoor gloves, or some other trick to deal with that problem that I didn't think of yet?

Comment: Just a thought; A lot of energy in the form of heat gets dissipated by a processor, then extracted through a vent. Surely this energy can be utilized to keep a user's hands warm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those gloves with the fingertips cut out might work.

[image]

There are also directional heaters. The beam of warmth may be focused enough that you could just aim at your hands.

[image]

Comment: I should be careful with a directional heater if working on a laptop, the last thing you want to do is apply heat to a device into which a lot of time and energy has gone into dissipating heat.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Smart. Agreed.